# Getting an error when trying to assign a List<Rank>

Tags: java, json, gson, bukkit

I have tried to parse a JSON formatted text from my Web API into an ArrayList of Rank.class, but I have been getting a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) error with message

> Cannot cast com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Here's some of my code:

```
# RankHandler.refresh()

this.ranks = new Gson().fromJson(Juke.INSTANCE.getApiHandler().request("/ranks").getJsonResponse(), new TypeToken<List<Rank>>() {}.getType());
```

```
# Rank.class

@Getter @AllArgsConstructor
public class Rank {
    private String id, displayName, prefix, inheritFromId;
    private ChatColor color;
    private List<String> permissions;
    private int weight;
    private boolean staff;
}
```

```
# Exception:

[19:11:59 WARN]: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive to com.google.gson.JsonObject
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:690)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at me.ma1de.juke.shared.api.APIRequest.getJsonResponse(APIRequest.java:54)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at me.ma1de.juke.shared.api.APIHandler.request(APIHandler.java:27)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at me.ma1de.juke.shared.api.APIHandler.request(APIHandler.java:52)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at me.ma1de.juke.shared.rank.RankHandler.refresh(RankHandler.java:44)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[19:11:59 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[19:11:59 WARN]: Exception in thread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 48"
[19:11:59 WARN]: org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: Plugin juke-bukkit v1.0-SNAPSHOT generated an exception while executing task 2
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.ma1de.juke.shared.rank.RankHandler.refresh(RankHandler.java:44)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
        ... 3 more
```

```
# What I am trying to parse as an array list of Rank.class

[{"id":"default","displayName":"Default","prefix":"","color":"WHITE","permissions":[],"weight":0,"staff":false}]
```

```
# Dependencies
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.ma1de.juke.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>Shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tried switching gson's version from [2.10.1](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-parent-2.10.1) to [2.8.6](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-parent-2.8.6), thought that downgrading gson would not cause this error, but it happened again.

Comment: I go for @AllaArgsConstructor and the fact that rank class does not appear to have a variable for "prefix":"", apart no value.

Comment: Is the JSON data possibly itself inside a JSON string, i.e. `"[{\"id\":\"default\",\"displayName\", ...`?

Comment: Try marking Rank class Seralizable by adding @Seralizable annotation

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the json strng you provided does not contain `inheritFromId` value which might be needed for deserializarion.

The problem might also be caused by `color` field which is written to be an object of the type `ChatColor` while represented as a `String` in json.